# reprojecting WorldImage File

Tags: gdal, jpg

I can reproject a GeoTiff file like this:

`gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:31467 -t_srs EPSG:4326 or11.tif or11_4326.tif`

How can I reproject a WorldImage File, i.e a jpg with an attached .jgW file?

Comment: Should be almost the same, except that you have to specify the output format `-of JPEG`.

Comment: Does the jpg have a known coordinate system or only the jgw file? To reproject it, you need the jpeg's coordinate system, not just the world file.